# ROS implementation of Behavior Trees?

Tags: ros, executive-smach

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have run through the tutorials for both [SMACH](http://www.ros.org/wiki/smach) and [teer](http://www.ros.org/wiki/executive_teer).  I am wondering if anyone has implemented a ROS package based on **behavior trees** as used in some AI game software?

Thanks!
patrick

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/74506/ros-implementation-of-behavior-trees?/) by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4046 on 2013-08-23

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have just discovered this [package](http://wiki.ros.org/decision_making_tools?distro=hydro)
which has its [own implementation](http://wiki.ros.org/decision_making/Tutorials/BehaviorTree) of behavior trees.

I haven't tried yet, but It might be what you are looking for.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Gonzalez-Pacheco](https://answers.ros.org/users/2660/victor-gonzalez-pacheco/) with karma: 396 on 2013-12-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2013-12-18**:
Excellent!  Thanks for the pointer.

**Comment by [mrjogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1576/mrjogo/) on 2016-06-07**:
Recently did my own searching, and also came across https://github.com/almc/behavior_trees as an implementation from this paper: [http://www.csc.kth.se/~almc/pdf/unified_bt_framework.pdf](http://www.csc.kth.se/%7Ealmc/pdf/unified_bt_framework.pdf)

**Comment by [addonics](https://answers.ros.org/users/27193/addonics/) on 2016-06-16**:
I actually found a stable behavior tree implementation here: https://github.com/miccol/ROS-Behavior-Tree . I first started first using the almc implementation, but the miccol one has the concept of "halt" that allows an action to be preempted.

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2016-06-16**:
I ended up writing my own Python implementation called [pi_trees](http://wiki.ros.org/pi_trees) which includes ROS wrappers for actions, topics and services.